# Unable to load the data from json files to bigquery, as the jsons have same key with different cases

Tags: json, google-bigquery, case-insensitive, google-cloud-storage

Our Data is in GCS bucket in new line delimited jsons. We create external and native tables in bigquery using those buckets as source.
While loading the data we are getting an error the json can not be loaded.
While analysing further we found that the jsons have same keys with different cases. The conflict happens because the json parsing is case sensistive and the bigquery column name is case insensitive.

Eg:

```
{
    "metrics": [
        {
            "labels": {
                "__name__": "name",
                "cluster_id": "cluster1",
                "cluster_profile": "dev",
                "cluster_region": "cloud",
                "container": "POD",
                "endpoint": "https-metrics",
                "id": "ID",
                "image": "IMAGE",
                "instance": "Instance",
                "namespace": "default",
                "node": "node",
                "pod": "pod"
            },
            "samples": [
                {
                    "value": 0.04,
                    "timestamp": 1654756143044
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "labels": {
                "__name__": "name",
                "cluster_id": "cluster1",
                "cluster_profile": "dev",
                "cluster_region": "cloud",
                "container": "POD",
                "endpoint": "https-metrics",
                "id": "ID",
                "Image": "IMAGE",
                "instance": "Instance",
                "namespace": "default",
                "node": "node",
                "pod": "pod"
            },
            "samples": [
                {
                    "value": 0.04,
                    "timestamp": 1654756143044
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here as you can see there are 2 labels image and Image.

Error:

```
Error in query string: Duplicate(Case Insensitive) field names: image and Image. Table: table1
```

Comment: Are the values of `image` and `Image` equal? Like are they supposed to be the same field?

Comment: Yes. The values are equal. 
But we are getting different jsons from different sources and we have two jsons having image and Image in each  in one json array

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach:

1. Format the keys of your json file to be in lowercase by running the command `gsutil cat gs://[YOUR-BUCKET-NAME]/[FILENAME].json | jq 'walk(if type=="object" then with_entries(.key|=ascii_downcase) else . end)' > [FILENAME].json`
2. Then run gsutil `cp` command to upload or store your formatted json file from your local to your GCS bucket.

Sample output:
[image]

Formatted json file uploaded in GCS bucket:

[image]

Comment: Hi @KrutiVyas, let me know if the provided workaround fixes the issue. If the answer solves the issue, you can accept it so the question will be marked as solved. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.).

Comment: The data is in PB. Like 1TB per hour. Transforming and copying the whole dataset will not be a cost effective solution. 

This would work for smaller dataset for sure. Thank you. 

I am looking for a flag or configuration so that the data loading could ignore the json key cases.